# Ubuntu 22.04, XRDP: connect to running session

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

I'm new to AskUbuntu, searched a lot about my issue but did not find any solution so far.

**My goal**

I would like to have a headless PC, autologin enabled, a dedicated piece of software started after autologin and connect with RDP to that existing locally started desktop session.

**My status**

Everything works but not the connection to via XRDP  to teh running session. Instead, a new session is opened and I can't see the started software.

**My setup**

1. a PC running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as desktop installation, standard GNOME desktop
2. XRDP was installed with

> sudo apt update

> sudo apt install xrdp -y

> sudo usermod -a -G ssl-cert xrdp

3. I can now connect with `Microsoft Remote Desktop` from another computer to the Linux computer but I can't connect to the already running session. Another sessin is opened.
4. Followinfg a post in AskUbuntu I tried various settings for the ports parameter (-1, ask-1, 3389, 5900)in the xrdp.ini file without any luck.

**My question**

is this possible? And what do I need to change?